# Sort POIs by distance from current location

Tags: sorting, geolocation, geospatial, distance

[Trover](http://www.trover.com/) is an awesome app: it shows you a stream of discoveries (POIs) people have uploaded - sorted by the distance from any location you specify (usually your current location). The further you scroll through the feed, the farther away the displayed discoveries are. An indicator tells you quite accurately how far the currently shown discoveries are (see screenshots on Website).

This is different from most other location based apps that deliver their results (POIs) based on fixed regions (e.g. give me all Pizzerias withing a 10km radius) which can be implemented using a single spacial datastructure (or an SQL engine supporting spatial data types). Deliverying the results the way Trover does is considerably harder:

- You can query POIs for arbitrary locations. Give Trover a location in the far East of Russia and it will deliver discoveries where the first one is 2000km away and continuously increasing from there.
- The result list of POIs is not limited by some spatial range. If you scroll long enough through the feed you will probably see discoveries which are on the other side of the globe.
- The above points require a semi-strict ordering of their POIs for any location. The fact that you can scroll down and reload more discoveries implies that they can deliver specific sections of the sorted data (e.g. give me the next 20 discoveries that are at least 100km away from my current location).
- It's fast, the fetching and distance indications are instant. The discoveries must be pre-sorted. I don't know how many discoveries they have in their DB but it must be more than what you want to sort ad hoc.

I find these characteristics quite remarkable and wonder how this is implemented. Any suggestions what kind of data-structure, algorithms or caching might be used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question. What do want an answer to?

Edit:
They might use a graph-database where one edge represent the distance between the nodes. That way you can get the distance by the relationships of nearby POIs. You would calculate the distance and create edges to nearby nodes. To get the distance of an arbitrary point you just do a circle-distance calculation, for another node you just add up the edges value as they represent the distance (this is for the case of getting the walking,biking, or car calculation). The adding up might not be the closest way but will give a relative indication which it seems like they use.

Comment: Is this an answer? I edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now. I don't expect a single answer, more a number of techniques which in combination can achieve the mentioned characteristics.

Comment: That's more like an answer! Do you mean the nodes are the POIs? Computing the distance between the current location and the POIs I think is relatively simple as each POIs has latitude/longitude attached to it. The tricky part is selecting the nodes (POIs) which are closest to the current location in the first place, assuming you have many many nodes. If I understand correctly you suggest doing some sort of breadth first search from the nearest node to find the next closest nodes?

Comment: You want to have it precalculated, you need a smart data structure to store.